# Paypal Error "return to your homepage and restart your activity. Try again in 30 min

Tags: paypal, try-catch

I wish you can help me. I have used Paypal Classic API to connect with Paypal Gateway. It was working before on sandbox environment. I connected to live paypal just to test the connection (no transaction) and I start to get the following error on both (Sandbox, and Live).

Please help meeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee :(:::
This is the error below:

"If you were making a purchase or sending money, we recommend that you check both your PayPal account and your email for a transaction confirmation after 30 minutes.

If you came to this page from another website, please return to that site (don't use your browser's Back button) and restart your activity.

If you came from PayPal's website, click the PayPal logo in the upper-left corner to return to our home page and restart your activity. You might have to log in again.
Dispatch Error, please check logfile for more information"

============================================================
End of the error

Many thanks dears,
Ray

Comment: No help for me :( Please gentlemen try.

Comment: Can you share the code you are using, and what you are sending over?  It may have something to do with what is being passed over in the API call.